# Transparent controls in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I have a problem with:

```
BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

It's not working correctly. I have a form with a blue background, and a picturebox with a picture loaded in it. It's not actually taking what's in the picture, but rather - the form's background color. Please tell me there's a simple way to go around this?

What you see in the following screenshot is a custom usercontrol with it's backColor set to transparent, on top of a picture, in a form with a blue background.

I need the usercontrol to display what's UNDER it, as real transparency, it should be showing the gradient and part of the image.

[image]

Comment: WinForms doesn't work well with this kind of thing. WPF is the go-to once again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the picture box to be the parent of the custom user control.

```
myControl.Parent = this.myPictureBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling "SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);" on your user control constructor.

more details at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Placed this line in the constructor:
`SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);`

Same effect as before